# Serialize a summary of a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-4.1

How can I include a summary of the associated objects rather than the objects itself.  For example, if a client has_many projects I could do this:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
  has_many :projects
end
```

But this will return all of the associated projects.  I would much rather bring back just a count of the projects, the url to download the full list of projects, the last time a project was updated, etc.

What is the best way to include a summary of the associated objects?

Ideally, for example the resulting JSON would look like this:

```
 {
  "id": 10,
  "name": "My Client",
  "projects": {
    "count": 5,
    "updated_at": "2014-09-09T13:36:20.000-04:00",
    "url": "https://my.baseurl.com/clients/10/projects"
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I got this to work:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :archive, :updated_at, :projects
  def projects
    collection = object.projects.to_a
    { count: collection.length,
      updated_at: collection.map(&:updated_at).max,
      url: projects_url }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an instance method:

```
class ClientSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :projects

  def project_count
    projects.size
  end
end
```

Comment: I would like to have them collected under the association. I updated my question to show what I mean.